# How to align text to the right side of an img without using float:left so it wont change the default parent div height

Tags: html, css

How to I align text to the right side of the image icon like the one in the example picture.

I would usually use  "`float:left`" but it's for a mobile responsive design so I prefer not using things like "`float:left`" because it ruins the red `div`s height with responsive designs.

I have to align the title, subsitle and a little square image.

[image]

Comment: can you show us your html/css?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/366kumc1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is easy to use float: left and NOT break the height of red border div.**

You only have to add **display: table-cell** to the **.app_top** block. Here's the solution:

```
.app_top {
    display: table-cell;
}
.app_top img {
    float: left;
}
```

See the working example. [Here's the code](http://jsfiddle.net/366kumc1/1/).

Comment: Its working but there is gap between image and text.  :(

Answer (score 2):

You could use `display: inline-block` instead.

```css
#main-container {
  border: 5px solid #3F3F3F;
  width: 270px;
}
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #7F0008;
  margin: 5px;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  background: #446C74;
  margin: 5px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.title, .sub-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 0;
}
.title {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.sub-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3F3F3F;
}
.img {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100/25);
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 5px solid #EBEAAE;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="title">Title</p>
      <p class="sub-title">Sub-Title</p>
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="title">Title</p>
      <p class="sub-title">Sub-Title</p>
      <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another option is to put the attribute in a parent div instead of the element

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="twoColumn">
         <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/444650714287972352/OXTvMFPl.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="twoColumn">
         <p> this is a testingalot test</p>
          <button> mybutton </button>

    </div>
</div
```

css:

```
#wrapper{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.twoColumn{
     width: 49%;
     float:left;
     border: 1px solid red;
}
button{
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
 } 

img{ 
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Equero/df2wvcet/

I hope it's help

Answer (score 0):

Most simple solution would be to change your markup structure by wrapping your `spans` in a div just the way you did with the image, then add `.app_top div{display:inline-block} .app_top div span{display:block}`

```css
.top{
 width: 95%;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 3%;
 padding-right: 3%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
}

.search{
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: none;
 background-color: #e3e3e6;
}

.search::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.items{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 50px;
}

.app{
 margin-left: 25px;
 margin-right: 25px; 
}
.app_top div{display:inline-block}
.app_top div span{display:block}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 
 <div class="top" >
  <input type="text" class="search" />
 </div>

<!-- Items -->

 <div class="items" style="border: 1px solid black; padding-top: "> 
  
  <div class="app" style="border: 1px solid red;" > 
  
  <div class="app_top">
   <div> 
    <img src="_img1.jpg" width="95"/>
   </div>
   <div>
                <span class="app_txt" style="border: 1px solid aqua;"> text text - House text house! Las...</span>
   <span class="ltd" style="border: 1px solid pink;"> textic-texttive ltd</span>
   <span class="" style="border: 1px solid blue;"> </span>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="app_bottom">
  
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.content contains all text in right side. If you use overflow:hidden the height of div will stay normal.

```
img { float:left; }
.content { overflow:hidden; }
```